# App doesn't install when working at 2 PC

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I've written a app for Android which is almost ready to use. Now i have moved my project-folder to Dropbox to work on it at 2 PC.

The compilation at the other PC works fine. The debugging at the emulator, too. But when I want to install it on my phone I have to uninstall it first. After this uninstallation it works fine.

Does somebody know, if this problem is normal, or how I can solve it?

Comment: You mean that if you build your app on your PC you can install it on the phone, but if you build it on the other PC, you have to uninstall it first?

Comment: It's normal. For fix this you should generate one keystore file and setup it to yours two PC. <Preferences->Android->Build>

Comment: I can't try it at the moment because I only have the first PC here right now ;) But I will try it later. I will let you know if it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what Pasha said:

1) On your first PC:

Open Eclipse, go to Window -> Preferences -> Android -> Build and get the path from "Default debug keystore" and put that file ("**debug.keystore**") on your second PC.

2) On the second PC:

Open Eclipse, go to Window -> Preferences -> Android -> Build.
Select "**Browse**" next to "Custom debug keystore" and select the "debug.keystore" file you got from your first PC.